# Eclipse CSV Download cuts off data

Tags: java, eclipse, csv, jdbc

I currently have a file download process in my java class, listed below, to take all the data in an SQL table and put it in a CSV file for user download. However, when I download the file, all the data is good except it will cut off at random points (usually around line 20 of the data, given there are at least over 100 lines of data). I want to ask, what if making the cutoff? Is it session time related or is the code just problematic?

```
    public String processFileDownload() {

    DataBaseBean ckear = new DataBaseBean();
    ckear.clearContens();
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
    Map<String, Object> m = fc.getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
    dbase = (DbaseBean) m.get("dbaseBean");
    message = (MessageBean) m.get("messageBean");
    dataBean = (DataBean) m.get("dataBean");
    dbmsUser = (DbmsUserBean) m.get("dbmsUserBean");
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    String path = fc.getExternalContext().getRealPath("/temp");
    String tableName = dbmsUser.getTableName();
    String fileNameBase = tableName + ".csv";
    java.net.URL check = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(
            "config.properties");
    File check2 = new File(check.getPath());
    path = check2.getParent();
    String fileName = path + "/" + dbmsUser.getUserName() + "_"
            + fileNameBase;

    File f = new File(fileName);
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    dbase.connect();
    dbase.setQueryType("SELECT");
    dbase.executeSQL("select * from " + tableName);
    if (dbase.getResultSet() == null) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("myForm3:errmess",
                new FacesMessage("Table doesn't exist!"));
        return "failed";
    }
    Result result = ResultSupport.toResult(dbase.getResultSet());
    downlaodedrows = result.getRowCount();
    Object[][] sData = result.getRowsByIndex();
    String columnNames[] = result.getColumnNames();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

        for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++) {
            sb.append(columnNames[i].toString() + ",");
        }

        sb.append("\n");

        fos.write(sb.toString().getBytes());

        for (int i = 0; i < sData.length; i++) {
            sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int j = 0; j < sData[0].length; j++) {
                sb.append(sData[i][j].toString() + ",");
            }

            sb.append("\n");
            fos.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
        }

        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    String mimeType = ec.getMimeType(fileName);
    FileInputStream in = null;
    byte b;

    ec.responseReset();
    ec.setResponseContentType(mimeType);
    ec.setResponseContentLength((int) f.length());
    ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
            + fileNameBase + "\"");

    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(f);
        OutputStream output = ec.getResponseOutputStream();
        while (true) {
            b = (byte) in.read();
            if (b < 0)
                break;
            output.write(b);
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        fc.responseComplete();
        return "SUCCESS";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    fc.responseComplete();
    return "SUCCESS";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are simply appending commas between values and it's likely one of the values you are writing contains a delimiter, line separator or quote character, which will "break" the CSV format if not correctly escaped.

It would be way easier and faster to use CSV library for that. [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) comes with pre-built routines to dump your resultset into properly formatted CSV. In your case, you could use this library in the following manner:

```
    ResultSet resultSet = dbase.getResultSet();

    // Configure the output format as needed before actually dumping the data:
    CsvWriterSettings writerSettings = new CsvWriterSettings(); //many settings here, check the tutorials & examples.
    writerSettings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
    writerSettings.setHeaderWritingEnabled(true); // we want the column names to be printed out as well.

    // Then create a routines object:
    CsvRoutines routines = new CsvRoutines(writerSettings);

    // The write() method takes care of everything. The resultSet and any other resources required are closed by the routine.
    routines.write(resultSet, new File(fileName), "UTF-8");
```

Hope this helps

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library. It's open source and free (Apache 2.0. license)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response and you are correct. However, do you know if there is a way to append "UTF-8" without the framework? I can't use it due to this being a specific project with limited resources.

Comment: Glad I could help. Just omit the "UTF-8" part and write "routines.write(resultSet, new File(fileName))" instead. You can also use a FileOutputStream or just any instance of java.io.Writer.